# Reverse a list without reversed command

Tags: python, list, reverse

I want to reverse a list on Python without use `reversed` command. Any ideas?
The query was to find another way to do the reverse the list without use any "standar" Python command like reverse. Thank in advance!

```
list = []
x = 1

#Import 20 random numbers
for i in range (0,20):
    list.append (x)

print (list)

for i in range (20,0,-1): # <-- I know, this is wrong. I used it as an example
    print (list[i])
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
list = []
    x = 1

    #Import 20 random numbers
    for i in range (0,20):
        list.append (x)

    print (list)

for i in range(len(list) - 1, -1, -1):
    print(list[i])
```

Comment: Also, you should pick a different name for your list besides `list`.  Currently, you are overshadowing the `list` built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) to step through the list backwards:

```
print(list[::-1])
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> lst[::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

In fact, if you test this with [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit), you will see that it is a lot faster than using `reversed`:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> lst = list(range(1000))
>>> timeit('list(reversed(lst))', 'from __main__ import lst')
18.91587534169846
>>> timeit('lst[::-1]', 'from __main__ import lst')
9.677450346342901
>>>
```

It is also less typing. :)

Comment: Is there any way to do it with for ? I think teacher want to do it with this way. 
Namely without use reversed, ::-1 etc.

By the way, thank for your answer!

Comment: Well, I suppose you could do `for i in range(len(list) - 1, -1, -1): print(list[i])`.  Note however that this an unusual and slightly unpythonic way of doing things.  Using `[::-1]` or `reversed` is how most Python programmers do what you want.

Comment: It works! The query was to find another way to do the reverse the list without use any "standar" Python command like reverse. Thank you again!